Is it possible to have a throwable entity inherit a tag from it's parent (thrower) in a minecraft datapack?
In my minecraft datapack I am working on, I have a problem on how I would create more "abilities" for a minigame, since tridents, armor stands, spectral arrows and regular arrows were already in use by other "abilities" and I would like to keep expanding it out.
I tried to make the snowball check if a player within 5 blocks (already an issue from a multiplayer standpoint) had the tag hasTag. I expected it to output Snowball thrown by tagged player as the code suggests but no such luck, since it just returned nothing.
The (non-functioning) that i tried to use is as follows:
tick.mcfunction:
execute as @a[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:iron_hoe"}}] run tag @s remove holding
execute as @a[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:wooden_hoe"}}] run tag @s add holding
execute as @a[tag=snow_thrower] run scoreboard players set @s hasTag 1
execute as @a[tag=!snow_thrower] run scoreboard players set @s hasTag 0
execute if entity @e[distance=..5,scores={hasTag=1}] as @e[type=snowball] at @s run say "Snowball thrown by tagged player"

load.mcfunction:
tellraw @a {"text": "Loading...", "color": "#FFFF60"}
scoreboard objectives add hasTag dummy
tellraw @a {"text": "Loaded Scoreboard", "color": "#00FF60"}

Any help would be appreciated, whether an idea on a better way to do it, or a fix to this already janky code.
